# Eclipse and cygwin - Error: Program "sh" not found in PATH

Tags: c++, eclipse, compiler-errors, cygwin

I am running the following code:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return
}
```

I get the following error message:

> Invoking autoreconf in build directory: C:/Users/madle/eclipse-workspace/hjbhjbjh/
>
> Configuration failed with error
>   (sh -c "autoreconf -i" 
>   Cannot run program "sh": Launching failed
>
> Error: Program "sh" not found in PATH
>   PATH=[C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Users\madle\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\eclipse;]
>   )

How can I prevent this error from occurring?

Comment: The problem is your compiler setup.

Comment: ***I am a beginner and trying to begin learning*** You picked one of the more difficult compiler setups to install.

Comment: for this code Eclipse is an an overkill. Anyway assuming that you installed Cygwin you need to add the cygwin\bin directory to your PATH.

Comment: I went to Project>properties>C/C++ general>GNU C++>Add>Fuile system> and clicked the C:\cygwin\bin folder. Still getting the same error message. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you had choiced the right "Perspective".

You need to select C++, after that hit "Build Project".

[image]

Also make sure you had choice toolchain that you had install in your computer. In you case need to point out cygwin:
[image]